# jquery .length- error says not valid property

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to see if there are any elements inside one div, and also, if there is more than one element in another div. If so, I want some things to happen. I've gotten errors running my script (not a valid property) and more of my js script doesn't get executed if it's below this. so, other than moving this script down my js page, what are my options? My logic seems fine, just the error bothers me.

```
var firstDiv = $('.firstDiv');
var secondDiv = $('.secondDiv');
if( (secondDiv).html().length > 0 || $(firstDiv).html().length > 1 ){
    make stuff happen
}
```

Comment: @ShaunakD: No, no difference.

Comment: If `.html()` does return `undefined` (so that `.length` throws) instead of a string, it means that your selector did not match any elements.

Comment: Are you sure it's not `#firstDiv` and `#secondDiv`? To me it makes no sense to make them classes instead of ids.

Comment: please add your html

Comment: I just noticed your second condition as well, there's no need to use the jQuery constructor again on firstDiv, it's already a jquery object.

Answer (score 0):

As MinusFour mentioned, make sure that your selectors are correct. If the JQuery object is empty, the `html()` method will return `null`. There is no `length` property on `null`.

You can see how many elements the JQuery object wraps using its `length` property:

```
$('.secondDiv').length // should be greater than 0
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
if((secondDiv.html() && secondDiv.html().length > 0) || ($(firstDiv).html() && $(firstDiv).html().length > 1)){
make stuff happen
}
```